# R: Distribution Function returns "random" values

Tags: r

I estimated a 5 dimensional normal copula and call the pCopula function with arbitrary upper bounds. As you can see the results vary when the same  function is called several times:

```
 library(copula)
normal.cop = normalCopula( c(0.5517099 ,0.3519115, 0.5681927, 0.4931297, 0.3733265, 0.4956172, 0.3931483, 0.4177506, 0.4112307, 0.6423421), dim=5, dispstr = "un") 

pCopula(c(0.4,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.9),normal.cop)
>0.07235714
pCopula(c(0.4,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.9),normal.cop)
>0.07233399
```

The function is obviously using some Monte Carlo integration methods because for identical set.seed values the results are the same:

```
set.seed(1)
pCopula(c(0.4,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.9),normal.cop)
>0.07234068
```

Where can I change the default settings of the function? I needs very reliable results and would like to set the number of iterations, error tolerance etc. manually. The function does not have any parameters to do that.

According to the [documentation](http://127.0.0.1:30167/library/copula/html/Copula.html) however the functions uses pmvnorm. There is no random component in pmvnorm and I can set iterations in pmvnorm. Is there any option to do that in pCoupla?

Comment: Thank you for asking me by e-mail  (I am the maintainer of `copula`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking me by e-mail  (I am the maintainer of `copula`).  Indeed, higher dimensional integration often works via monte-carlo integration, and in this case is -- as you found -- dependent on R's `.Random.seed`.   In the CRAN version of `copula` you cannot yet influence the integration algorithm of pCopula() for the normal- and t-copulas.  The next version of copula -- a snapshot is available from R-forge (but not by direct installation or tarball .. these are "old") at https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=600  -- does provide the possibility and shows some examples.

The good news is that for low dimensions, d=2,3.. possibly up to 5,6 or so,
there are non-random algorithms already available [from package `mvtnorm`]